# How can I trace failed requests on IIS 10 Server Farm

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

how can I trace these errors on an IIS 10 server farm. I have enable trace logging but all that gives me is a log of the requests coming in. I cant see why the failures have occured? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to figure out what does "Failed Requests" mean：

> Displays the number of requests that failed, including requests that
>   are a result of a connection error or a status code that matches a
>   live traffic failure code.

So there are different troubleshooting steps for **connection error** and **error status code**.
https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/what-the-failed-requests-counter-in-arr-really-means

First of all, you need to **check IIS log**, so we would know what the error message is. 502.3, 502.4 also represent different means. Failed request tracing also could provide more information.

Then you need to go to your back-end server and check their **IIS log**. It should tell you whether an error response was returned from backend server.

If you can find an error response status like 404 in backend server at the same time ARR return 502.3 error.Then you only have to focus on that error just like troubleshooting normal asp.net exception.

However, if you can't find the error message anywhere or win32-status code display an connection time out . Then it would probably be a connection error.

To troubleshooting ARR connection error, you may need to trace **etl log** on wininet or http.sys tool. Then analyze the log file via network monitor

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2009/09/08/part-2-exploring-and-decoding-etw-providers-using-event-log-channels/